# Giravion, gyropode : graphie francisante pour certains transports, comparaison de l'emploi de l'élément/préfixe gyro- ?

Tags: vocabulaire, orthographe, terminologie, préfixes, transports

Le préfixe [**gyro-**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gyro-) (gir-, gyr-, giro-, gyro-), avec l'idée du cercle/de tourner. Au lexique en [aéronautique](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bibliotheque/dictionnaires/terminologie_moteur-aeronefs/fiches/index_fra.html) on trouve le [*giravion*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8877653) (*rotorcraft, rotary-wing aircraft*), ou si l'on veut l'[*aéronef*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a%C3%A9ronef) ([aéro-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a%C3%A9ro-), aussi astro[*nef*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nef)) *à [voilure tournante](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8886877)*, par opposition à [fixe](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=10435452) ; l'hélicoptère en est le prototype le plus connu (GDT).<sup>1</sup> Plus précisément encore, semble-t-il, on a le [*girodyne*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=10884286) (*gyrodyne*), ou le « giravion dont la sustentation est assurée par une hélice entraînée par un organe moteur, et la propulsion, par un dispositif distinct » (GDT).

---

Différemment, on a le *gyropode* ([GDT](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26503183), [FT](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/COGE592?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=gyropode&francetermeSearchDomaine=0)) , souvent reconnu sous la marque de commerce « Segway » (le *self-balancing personal transporter*) :

> Véhicule électrique monoplace, constitué d'une plateforme munie de
>   deux roues sur laquelle l'utilisateur se tient debout, d'un système de
>   stabilisation [gyroscopique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gyroscopique) et d'un manche de maintien et de conduite.
>
> [ *FranceTerme*, vedette [*gyropode*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/COGE592?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=gyropode&francetermeSearchDomaine=0), référant au [Journal officiel du 26/05/2009](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do;jsessionid=BDCB14FD6AEF49454043EE1B1AF651E2.tpdila18v_1?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000020665543&dateTexte=&oldAction=rechJO&categorieLien=id&idJO=JORFCONT000020664898) ; on a aussi [*polo à...*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/SPOR426?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=gyropode&francetermeSearchDomaine=0) ]

C'est-à-dire que c'est un [*-pode*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-pode), un (petit) véhicule (à stabilisation) gyroscopique. En résumé ce ne sont pas les roues motrices qui [tournent](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope), alors qu'en aéronautique ce sont les voilures des hélicoptères. Et dans tous les cas on est loin du [cycle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cycle/1)/[*cyclo-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cyclo-/2) employé avec le « véhicule à deux ou trois roues mu par les jambes ou par un moteur » (TLFi).

---

- Pourquoi avec les termes d'aéronautique on a l'orthographe avec le
  *i* (gir-) et non le *y* (gyro-) ; est-ce une illustration de la plus grande *francisation* de la graphie de ces mots vu l'importance du
  secteur des transports ; y a-t-il généralement une tendance à écrire
  *gir-* plutôt que *gyro-* avec les mots plus récents, le cas échéant est-ce comparable avec d'autres éléments formants contenant la lettre
  *y* ; à terme beaucoup de mots formés avec l'élément *gyro-* risquent-ils de s'écrire *gir-* ?
- Comment qualifie-t-on l'(intensité de) emploi de l'élément *gyro-*
  avec le *gyropode* pour la stabilisation et non pour la motricité
  quand on le compare avec l'emploi dans *giravion/girodyne* ; c'est
  qu'il faut une connaissance plus grande des sciences/technologies, il
  me semble, et la simple connaissance de la roue ne suffit pas pour
  connaître le fonctionnement du *gyroscope* et donc éventuellement
  reconnaître que c'est ce à quoi on fait référence dans le *gyropode*
  ; est-ce bien senti, mieux qu'avec le *giravion/girodyne* ?
- [ Une curiosité, mais connaît-on incidemment ce qui est au *girodyne*
  l'hélicoptère du *giravion* ? ]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Et c'est comme d'une pierre deux coups en effet parce qu'en anglais je n'avais jamais compris cette histoire de *fixed/rotary(-)wing(s) aircraft* même si je savais que l'avion appartenait à la première et que les hélices de l'hélicoptère ont évidemment des surfaces manœuvrables etc. mais là ça prend tout son sens.</sub>

Comment: Tous ces terms ne sont vraiment pas courants, voire semi-inconnus du grand public.

Comment: Je croyais que le gyropode était le véhicule plus ou moins inverse du Segway: une roue centrale et deux plateformes latérales pour les deux pieds, le tout sans guidon.

Answer (score 1):

On peut noter que les [deux préfixes gir- et gyr- peuvent souvent s'employer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/giravion), avec des préférences selon les mots.

Si on observe quels mots, ce sont souvent les plus anciens (19 ème siècles ou plus tôt), qui employaient le préfixe gyr-

Les termes en gir- paraissent plus récents, plus techniques (aviation, girodyne), et moins nombreux.

Les termes plus communs sont plutôt en gyr- (gyroscope, gyrophare). Il y en a tout une série : gyrocompas, gyrostat, ...

à noter que gyropode n'est pas encore vraiment rentré dans les dictionnaires (en ligne en tous cas), même s'il a été accepté par la commission de terminologie citée et visible sur France Terme, et pleins de sites de ventes !